# Will I get refund on my application if I cancel now?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a pakistani national and I came to Netherlands on a work visa. I applied for uk tourist visa but I think I made a mistake. It asked me about my status in the Netherlands and I replied I am a permanent residence but I have a residence permit. My appointment is in two days. I can cancel my application but will I get a full refund?

[image]

Comment: Do you actually want a refund, or do you just want to make a correction? If you want a refund, go ahead and cancel and you'll get whatever refund is available. If you want to make a correction [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71639/clerical-error-in-uk-visa-application-but-form-already-submitted-what-should) may help.

Comment: I want to make a correction

Comment: but this was from a drop down. I had two options and I selected this one at first but then I corrected it but the updates must have not saved. Can I still cross it out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About UK visa fee refund](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117781/about-uk-visa-fee-refund)

Comment: @Giorgio I don't think that's a good duplicate target. The asker here has an X-Y question: they want to correct their application but they're asking about cancelling instead.

Comment: @DavidRicherby understood: I took the question and last sentence to be what is being asked, and just saw OP's comment. I'll withdraw the VTC; TY.

Comment: @cannon fooder , hi i did my oine application but i forgott to add one lf my visit in turkey ,how can i proceed now? I will be looking forward for you reply . Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get a full refund. It might take upto 6 weeks for the funds to be available in your account.

Source: experience